# What is the Firebase RefBuilder.onOperation<T> method?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am wondering what the onOperation method of functions.database.RefBuilder is for as I can not find any information about it in the [documentation.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.database.RefBuilder)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From looking at the [code of `onOperations`](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/master/src/providers/auth.ts#L93) in the [`firebase-functions` repo](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions), it seems that `onOperation` is the common method that all the others call.

For example, here is the implementation of `onDelete`:

> ```
>  onDelete(
>     handler: (user: UserRecord, context: EventContext) => PromiseLike<any> | any
>   ): CloudFunction<UserRecord> {
>     return this.onOperation(handler, 'user.delete');
>   }
> ```

So this (and all other `on...` methods) calls `onOperation` for its actual work, since so much of the implementation of these methods overlap.

I'm actually not sure why `onOperation` is showing up in the auto-complete, since it is clearly marked as a `private` method:

> ```
> private onOperation(...
> ```

Comment: Thank you for detailed explanation. Strange it shows in the auto-complete, that is why I got confused. I am using Visual Studio Code 1.29.1.